# Possible to create a button with two clickable areas?

Tags: android, button, clickable

Is it possible to create a button in android with two clickable areas? If so how? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add two buttons and use background images and set margins to 0, so that they practically look like a single button.

Comment: Simply using negative margins I was able to get the effect I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could create two buttons that look like one button.  Place the two buttons right next to each other.  Create a bitmap image that covers both buttons.  Cut the image in half. Set the background image of the buttons to the two bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

first answer NO. 
but you can put two label combined have same button type view. put both label (or any other view) into same layout. set the listener for that layout.

Answer (score -2):

You can use an image with map parts and each part will execute a different javascript.
The image will act as a button with different target actions.

For example look at the code [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_imagemap)

```
<img src ="planets.gif" width ="145" height ="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
<area shape ="rect" coords ="0,0,82,126"
onmouseover="writeText('The Sun and the gas giant planets like Jupiter are by far the largest objects in our Solar System.')"
href ="sun.htm" target ="_blank" alt="Sun" />

<area shape ="circle" coords ="90,58,3"
onmouseover="writeText('The planet Mercury is very difficult to study from the Earth because it is always so close to the Sun.')"
href ="mercur.htm" target ="_blank" alt="Mercury" />

<area shape ="circle" coords ="124,58,8"
onmouseover="writeText('Until the 1960s, Venus was often considered a twin sister to the Earth because Venus is the nearest planet to us, and because the two planets seem to share many characteristics.')"
href ="venus.htm" target ="_blank" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```